# Using 1GB and 4GB ram sticks: worth it?

Tags: laptop, memory, performance, upgrade

I have a laptop running Linux with a 4GB RAM stick that came with it. It's a DDR3 1066 MHz stick. I also have a 1GB DDR3 1333 MHz stick lying around.

I've read somewhere that it might not be good to pair up RAM sticks that are not equal in a computer (the set should be symmetrical), so if they were both 1333 MHz or both 1066 MHz I wouldn't be asking this. But since the 1GB one is faster, is it advantageous to install both and end up with 5GB of RAM?

This question relates to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/920618/how-important-is-to-have-matching-speed-of-ram) which says that the speed bottlenecks to the slowest rate, which I think would mean that they will both work at 1033. Does that mean that I should then install both RAMs?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running a 64-bit kernel right?

Comment: What you read doesn't apply at all to your case.  With only one 4GB module, that will operate in single channel mode.  Adding a mismatched RAM module will also operate in single channel mode.  There's no performance degradation.

Comment: @sawdust Hey do you have any source on that so I read on it?

Comment: @TomCho -- What you read was describing the requirements for dual (or triple) channel operation of memory.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture

Answer (score 1):

Your faster stick will downclock to the speed of the slower stick. As the stick you'd be adding is faster than your current one, you won't notice any drawback from this.

My usual advice would be to just try it. It won't do any harm and if you did feel it was in any way slower it's a simple job to reverse it.

Comment: Is there any application that can objectively measure the performance of the computer regarding the RAM change? Because I have done this test before but I felt no difference. Maybe because there was indeed no difference but maybe because there isn't that much difference to be "felt" from 4GB to 5GB.

Comment: You won't notice any difference in performance unless your machine is actually utilizing the extra 1GB. Usually this would be when you have a lot of processes open. You can check under the performance tab in task manager how much you're using and have free. There are a number of tests you can do to see the actual speed of the ram, search 'RAM benchmark' and you'll find a large selection.

Comment: I'm using Linux so I can't use windows software (to test RAM at least), but I'll search for "RAM benchmark" programs and then I'll get back to you.

Comment: You can use the command `free -m` to see how much RAM you're using and have available under most distros.

Comment: Thanks, mate, but I already know that. I'll look for something aimed towards performance. Cheers

Comment: @TomCho -- Use [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).  On startup it'll report memory (and cache) access rates.  I typically run this utility overnight after installing new memory modules.  To test the benefit of increased memory capacity, you may need to stress test the system (e.g. multiple processes), rather than run just one program.